# How do c++ compilers find an extern variable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I compile this program by g++ and clang++. There has a difference:
g++ prints 1, but clang++ prints 2.
It seems that
g++: the extern varible is defined in the shortest scope.
clang++: the extern varible is defined in the shortest global scope.

Does C++ spec has any specification about that?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
static int i;
static int *p = &i;

int main() {
  int i;
  {
    extern int i;
    i = 1;
    *p = 2;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

other.cpp

```
int i;
```

version: g++: 7.4.0/ clang++:10.0.0
compilation: $(CXX) main.cpp other.cpp -o extern.exe

Comment: The compiler doesn't do anything with extern except mark them as variables that have external references, the linker is what tries to resolve the links between all the compiled object files.

Comment: An excellent (if strange) question! Playing around with your code in `MSVC` and `clang-cl` (both give `2`), it seems that the `extern int i` is completely ignored by both: even if I don't link in the `other.cpp` file, the program builds and runs.

Comment: @SPlatten Presumably, as the linker doesn't need to 'resolve' the reference to `i`, it doesn't try.

Comment: Related old suspended GCC bug can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14769) and corresponding open Clang bug [here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18552)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[[basic.link/7]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#7) should be the relevant part of the Standard. In the current draft, it says:

> The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a variable declared by a block scope `extern` declaration have linkage. If such a declaration is attached to a named module, the program is ill-formed. If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage, ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope, such that the block scope declaration would be a (possibly ill-formed) redeclaration if the two declarations appeared in the same declarative region, the block scope declaration declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If there is more than one such matching entity, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope entity receives external linkage. **If, within a translation unit, the same entity is declared with both internal and external linkage, the program is ill-formed.**

Note that the subsequent example almost exactly matches your case:

```
static void f();
extern "C" void h();
static int i = 0;               // #1
void g() {
  extern void f();              // internal linkage
  extern void h();              // C language linkage
  int i;                        // #2: i has no linkage
  {
    extern void f();            // internal linkage
    extern int i;               // #3: external linkage, ill-formed
  }
}
```

So, the program should be ill-formed. The explanation is below the example:

> Without the declaration at line #2, the declaration at line #3 would link with the declaration at line #1. Because the declaration with internal linkage is hidden, however, #3 is given external linkage, making the program ill-formed.

Comment: The program in the example is ill-formed because there is no i with external linkage *defined* anywhere. This is not the case with OP's example.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. But the rule applies to a translation unit: _If, within a translation unit, the same entity is declared with both internal and external linkage, the program is ill-formed._.

Comment: The answer only applies to C++17 and later, see resolution of [CWG issue 426](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#426). It seems to me that GCC was correct before that change.

Comment: OK it looks like I was reading the previous edition of the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Clang gives a right result. Even though per the rule of the current standard, the program shouldn't be ill-formed. Note the emphasized wording:

> If, within a translation unit, **the same entity** is declared with both internal and external linkage, the program is ill-formed.

The entity declared at `#3` and the entity declared at `#1` are not the same entity, because of the below rule:

> Two names that are the same and that are declared in different scopes shall denote the same variable, function, type, template or namespace if
>
> > - both names have external linkage or else both names have internal linkage and are declared in the same translation unit; and
> > - [...]

They're not, one has `internal linkage` and the other has `external linkage`, so they do not denote the **same** entity, hence the code does not violate the [basic.link#6]. Moreover, the example follows [basic.link#6] remains a wrong interpretation about variable `i`.

P1787 has clarified this example. It says:

```cpp
static void f();
extern "C" void h();
static int i = 0;               // #1
void gq() {
  extern void f();              // internal linkage
  extern void g();              // ::g, external linkage
  extern void h();              // C language linkage
  int i;                        // #2: i has no linkage
  {
    extern void f();            // internal linkage
    extern int i;               // #3: <del>ex</del>internal linkage
  }
}
```

<del>Without</del> Even though the declaration at line #2 hides the declaration at line #1, the declaration at line #3 <del>would link with the</del>still redeclar<del>ation</del>es <del>at line</del> #1<del>.</del> <del>Because the declaration with</del> and receives internal linkage <del>is hidden, however, #3 is given external linkage, making the program ill-formed</del>.

That means, In your example, the variable `i` introduced by declaration `extern int i` will link with the variable `i` declared by `static int i`. So, print `2` is the right behavior.

Comment: Relevant CWG page [P1787](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r5.html) [basic.link] and +1 for the update.

Comment: If the entities are not the same if they defer by linkage, how to violate the first rule? :D

Comment: @LanguageLawyer which is the first rule you refer to?

Comment: _If, within a translation unit, the same entity is declared with both internal and external linkage, the program is ill-formed._

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  I didn't say the code violated that rule.  Because they're not the **same** entity per [basic.link#9](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#9), similar for [issue 426](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue426) https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/msg1413. Maybe you mean that I shouldn't say `violate` instead `doesn't satisfy that rule`?

Comment: @jackX: P1787 also rewrites the rules for declarations declaring the same entity, making these as well as the ill-formed `namespace N {extern int i; static int i;}` do so.

Comment: @DavisHerring  I haven't read that part. P1787 seems to have resolved a lot of defectives in the current standard, for these defectives I have asked many questions on SO ago.

Comment: @DavisHerring  I don't know  why `#3` and `#1` are the same entity? According to:  Two declarations of entities declare the same entity if, considering declarations of unnamed types to introduce their names for linkage purposes, if any ([dcl.typedef], [dcl.enum]), they correspond ([basic.scope.scope]), have the **same target scope** that is not a function or template parameter scope, and...  It seems that `#1`, `#2` and `#3` they correspond(The term definitions of "Two declarations correspond" seems like doesn't consider the scope, only the names are same).

Comment: @DavisHerring  Apparently, they do not have the same target scope. So how could them be considered the same entity?

Comment: @jackX: `extern` affects the target scope ([dcl.meaning]).

Comment: @DavisHerring  Oops, it seems that it doesn't reflect in  P1787.